# If $R=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\:$ and $\:S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\:$ and $\sqrt{a_n}<b_n$ what can be concluded?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

> Consider the infinite sums $R=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\:$ and $\:S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\:$ and $\: Q = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n$.
>
> It is known that $a_n>0$, $b_n>0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, and that $c_n=\frac{1}{n}$.
>
> Lastly, $\sqrt{a_n}<b_n$ for all $n$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{b_n}{c_n} = 1$.
>
> What can be concluded about the convergence/divergence of $R$ and $S$?

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{b_n}{c_n} = 1$, $Q$ and $S$ are equivalent. Since $Q=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ is a known divergent sum, then $S$ is also divergent. However, can we conclude anything for $R$? If we were given $a_n<b_n$ instead of $\sqrt{a_n}<b_n$ then I could for certain say that $R$ is divergent, but that is not what we are given. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it is false that "if we were given $a_n<b_n$ instead of $\sqrt{a_n}<b_n$ then [you] could for certain say that R is divergent" (take e.g. $b_n=\frac1n,a_n=\frac1{2n^2}$).

But happily, $\sqrt{a_n}<b_n,$ i.e. $a_n<b_n^2$. Then, $\frac{a_n}{1/n^2}<\left(\frac {b_n}{c_n}\right)^2$ and the sequence $\left(\frac {b_n}{c_n}\right)$ is convergent hence bounded, say by $M>0$, hence $a_n<\frac {M^2}{n^2}$. Since $\sum\frac1{n^2}$ is a convergent series, so is $\sum a_n.$